# Touchpad driver Ubuntu 18:04 automatically stops working and only works after restart

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I have strange problem over asus laptop. My touchpad driver freezes occasionaly, and when I tried to find using `xinput --list` it did not appear over there. Then I have to restart my system to make it work and after restart upon running the `xinput --list` it appears as `↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad`

How can I fix this problem ?